# GoDaddy Domain name changes to IP address

Tags: ubuntu, ip, webserver, apache2

I am running a personal Apache webserver on Ubuntu using a domain name from GoDaddy.  When I navigate to my site using my domain name the URL in the browser changes to the public IP address.

I found this [same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38471517/domain-name-changes-to-ip-address) but there isn't a answer provided I have not been able to fix it.

Does anyone know or if there could be a different issue with my configuration?

Comment: Are you specifying UseCanonicalName ON in your apache config?